# Google app engine Datastore query

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have written this code for google app for storing and retriving the data enteries and displaying them on the browser window.The code is getting compiled but the how do I check if it is storing any values and further the SQL syntax which I have written is correct or not?

```
import cgi
import datetime
import urllib
import wsgiref.handlers
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class store(db.Model):
    cell = db.StringProperty()
    message = db.StringProperty()
    time = db.StringProperty()
    dateauto=db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class Getdata(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def prog (self,strg):
        message_split=strg.split('\n')
        message_split_second=strg.split(',')
        m_list=message_split[1:]
        collect_strings=''
        for j in m_list:
            collect_strings=collect_strings+j

        message_txt=collect_strings

        message_date=message_split_second[4]
        message_date=message_date.replace('"',"")
        dates=message_date

        message_time=message_split_second[5]
        message_time=message_time.split('/n')
        message_time=message_time[0]
        message_time=message_time.replace('"',"")
        temp=message_time.split('+')
        message_time=temp[0]
        times=message_time

        cell_number=message_split_second[2]
        cell_number=cell_number.replace('"',"")
        cellnum=cell_number
        return message_txt,dates,times,cellnum

    def post(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        strg=self.request.get('a')
        message_txt,dates,times,cellnum = self.prog(strg)
        log=store(cell=cellnum,message=message_txt,time=times)
        log.put()
        self.response.out.write(" ")

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        dataout=db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM store",
                            "ORDER BY dateauto")  
    for message in dataout:
        self.response.out.write(dataout)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                           ('/sign', Getdata)],debug=True)
def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

'

Comment: Typically, when I am using SQL in python, I insert a print of the SQL statement I am confident in and run the printed test case in an SQL browser. This lets me check syntax and function. IDK if this is a possible for your current situation though.

Comment: Test it out? It's not clear to me what the actual question is here.

Answer (score 0):

Access the server from the admin port instead of the normal port (For my current project i would use localhost:8004 instead of localhost:13080 in the browser). Click the Datastore Viewer tab and see what is stored.

P.S. In Datastore, GQL is used instead of SQL. This is like SQL except all queries begin with SELECT *, and there are no joins.